# How to transform string into object by Lodash

Tags: javascript, string, object, lodash

How to transform `"t=1&m=6&r=2"` to `{t:1, m:6, r:2}` by lodash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split the string and use [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/#fromPairs) for getting an object.

If necessary you might use [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) for decoding the string with elements like `%20`.

```js
var string = decodeURI("t=1&m=6&r=%20"),
    object = _.fromPairs(string.split('&').map(s => s.split('=')));
    
console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with simple javascript using `split()` and [`Array#reduce()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn6Na0teDVAhVMQ48KHeP1AfQQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) function

```js
var str = 't=1&m=6&r=2';

var res = str.trim().split('&').reduce(function(a, b) {
  var i = b.split('=');
  a[i[0]] = i[1];
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

**using lodash**

```js
var str = 't=1&m=6&r=2';

    var res = _.reduce(_.split(str.trim(),'&'),function(a, b) {
      var i = b.split('=');
      a[i[0]] = i[1];
      return a;
    }, {})
    
    console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a browser, you can use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) class. It's not part of *lodash*, it's just part of standard JavaScript. It's not supported in IE yet, but you can use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill).